# onEndReached is sometimes working and sometimes not

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a FlatList and implemented pagination to call on End to fetch more data. So, I added `onEndReached` it is working sometimes but sometimes not. Also, it requires scrolling to the last item for it to work if it worked. So, can I call it for example before the last 2 items?

```js
<View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column' }}>
  <FlatList
    keyExtractor={(item) => item._id}
    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
    data={people}
    renderItem={renderUserItem}
    onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
    onEndReached={updatePeople}
  />
</View>
```

Comment: Can you show logic that handle "people"?

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue for that here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14312. Looks like a lot of people are experiencing the same. There is a suggestion to change the onEndReachedThreshold to value bigger that 0, for example: 0.3.